# Use SOSL with REST API with PHP to get data data from Salesforce

Tags: php, rest, api, syntax, salesforce

I need to get the data from the leads and contacts from Salesforce through the REST API. As I read the **UNION** is not supported by Salesforce and we need to use a SOSL to get data.

For this I am using a below code

```
    $url = $instance_url. '/services/data/v37.0/search/?q= FIND {rohit} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Lead(email), Contact(email)';
    $urlcurl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));
    curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $urljson_response = curl_exec($urlcurl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($urlcurl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        die("Error: call to URL failed with status $status, response $urljson_response, curl_error " . curl_error($urlcurl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($urlcurl));
    }
    curl_close($urlcurl);
    return json_decode($urljson_response);
```

but it is returning a response like

```
Error: call to URL failed with status 400, response , curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: the response body would have more details, but i'd imagine its because you are not URLencoding the sosl query in your URL.

Comment: Did you consider using the SalesForce PHP toolkit?